# Excel 2016 conditional formatting is not working with AND

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to color rows automatically where a given condition is true, using conditional formatting.
For example, color the row if there is something in its D column: `=INDIRECT("D"&ROW())<>""`
This works fine.

However if i try something more complex just nothing happens, even is I push Ctr+Alt+F9. Specifically, this does not work:

```
=AND(INDIRECT("D"&ROW())<>"",INDIRECT("F"&ROW())="X")
```

It is supposed to color the row in which column D is not empty and column F contains an X. If I put it right into the sheet (into one of its cells) it works great. Evaluates true when it is supposed to and false when it is supposed to be false. Nonetheless, when I try to use it for conditional formatting (although the rule does get added) it has no effect; It does not color the cells it is supposed to.

What is the issue? How could I resolve it?

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, but I can reproduce the problem. To verify that the problem is with `AND`, I checked that `=AND(INDIRECT("D"&ROW())<>"")` has no effect while `=INDIRECT("D"&ROW())<>""` colours the rows where column D is not empty.

Comment: It appears that the problem occurs when using both `AND` and `INDIRECT`. Using the answer from the duplicate question, `=AND($D2<>"",$F2="X") works (this assumes the first row of the range is row 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments this is **NOT** the way to use conditional formatting - use cell references like Blackwood says, e.g.

`=AND(D2<>"",F2="x")`

....but the specific problem here is `ROW` function. I don't know why it's OK on the worksheet and not in CF but `ROW` function actually returns an "array" not a number, even though it's a single number, so on row 2, for example `ROW()` returns the array {2}. In some circumstances Excel has trouble processing that array, so the solution is to wrap in another function like `SUM` or `MAX`, like this:

`=AND(INDIRECT("D"&SUM(ROW()))<>"",INDIRECT("F"&SUM(ROW()))="X")`

although I note it also works without `SUM` if you multiply the conditions instead of using `AND`, i.e.

`=(INDIRECT("D"&ROW())<>"")*(INDIRECT("F"&ROW())="X")`

Note: `COLUMN` function sometimes displays the same behaviour